# Why defaultValue from React hook form can not work in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, forms, react-router, react-hook-form

I stuck in a problem. I am using [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Quickstart)
in my shipment component everything has gone well but while i try to use react hook form for my shipment component and setting default value on these component it's not work accurately. My code is given below:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { UserContext } from '../../App';
import './Shipment.css';

const Shipment = () => {
const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = 
useForm();

const [loggedInUser,setLoggedInUser] = useContext(UserContext);

const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log('form submitted',data);}

console.log(watch("example")); // watch input value by passing the name 
of it

return (
  
  <form className="ship-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    {/* <input defaultValue={loggedInUser.email} 
 {...register("example")} /> */}
    <input name="name" defaultValue={loggedInUser.name} 
 {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })} placeholder="Your 
  Name" />  
    {errors.name && <span className="error">Name is required</span>}
    <input name="email" defaultValue={loggedInUser.email} 
  {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })} 
  placeholder="Email address"/>  
    {errors.email && <span className="error">Email is required</span>}

    <input name="address" {...register("exampleRequired", { required: 
    true })} placeholder="address"/>  
    
    {errors.address && <span className="error">Address is 
required</span>}
    
    <input name="phone" {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true 
    })} placeholder="Phone number"/>  
    {errors.phone && <span className="error">Phone Number is 
  required</span>}
    
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
);
};

export default Shipment;
```

**when i attempt to sign in by using email :**
[image]

**i set default value on name and email field but it's not work except name**
[image]

**and my console show only name except all data**
[image]

**Actually i need all data and set default value on a specific field**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

Before

```
<input name="email" defaultValue={loggedInUser.email} 
  {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })} 
  placeholder="Email address"/>
```

After:

```
<input defaultValue={loggedInUser.email} 
  {...register("email", { required: true })} 
  placeholder="Email address"/>
```

All of your `register` have the same name, that's why it doesn't work.

See the [register API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register)